# hide on element and show other element in jquery

Tags: hide, element, show

$(document).ready(function(){

```
            $(".btn").hide();





          $(".about input").on('click',function(){





               $(".about input").hide();




               $(".btn").show();





          });
      });
```

" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">




              
                 save as
                 cover
                 logo
              





              
              save

```
          <select name="save">
             <option selected="selected">save as<option>
             <option value="coverimage">cover<option>
             <option value="logo">logo<option>
          </select>





          <input type="file" name="image"></input>




          <button class="btn">save</button>
          </form>
```

initially hiding ".btn", but after clicking ".about input" want to hide ".about input" and show ".btn"

Comment: Do you have class "about "on you code?

Comment: Please put the whole code including the about class